# Suppose that S and T each have cardinality c. Show that $S\cup T $ also has cardinality c.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I tried to use the Cantor-Bernstein Theorem. First, we have $S\subset S\cup T$, so that $\left | S \right |\leqslant \left | S\cup T\right | $. This implies $\left | S\cup T \right |\geqslant c$. But I don't know how to prove the opposite direction. Could someone help me with it? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** $S=_c[0,1], T=_c[2,3]{}$.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Do you mean that S∪T ⊂ R, so that ∣S∪T∣⩽ ∣R∣=c. I don't understand that since c is a finite number, how could S, T has infinite elements?

Comment: @LiangkaiHu I do mean that $|S\cup T|\leq |\mathbb R|=\mathfrak c$.But I don't get what you mean with $\mathfrak c$ being a finite number.